# How to reinstall nginx from source? (was installed with apt-get)

Tags: linux, installation, nginx

I want to install [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#Installation) module.

The problem is it requires that nginx is installed from source. I have it installed via `apt-get install`, and it is already serving web pages.

So which steps would you follow to change from one to the other? If possible I would like them to use the same paths. In the example it uses /opt, but apt-get installed it in a different place (I see entries in /etc, /lib, /usr/bin, /usr/share).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic procedure is to remove the installed version, and then install the new one:

```
    sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

Now, download the source tar ball of what you want to install and extract it:

```
    wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.3.11.tar.gz
    tar xvvzf nginx-1.3.11.tar.gz
```

The files you see in `/etc` and `/lib` are settings and service scripts and the like. They will be there no matter where you install `nginx`, `apt` installs `nginx` to `/usr`.

So, tell the included `configure` script to install in `/usr`:

```
cd nginx-1.3.11/
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Then compile and install:

```
make
sudo make install
```